# problem centering image in TABLE > TBODY > TR > TD in IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, image

I'm trying to center an image in table cell and all's well in every browser except IE7 (don't have to worry about IE6!!!).

Table looks like this:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="block.productgrid.image">
            <img width="125" height="100" alt="Alternate text" src="some-pix.jpg">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The image is align left, ... there are no external styles affecting this that I can discern.  The only way that works for me is using javascript and applying equal padding to the TD, but that's an extremely heavy handed fix. What could POSSIBLY be causing this?!?
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Where does it say align left? Im not seeing that..

Comment: `class="block.productgrid.image"` - class names cannot contain dots

Comment: ... tried all that. The ID value is 'cms' generated - 0 control over that.

Comment: @Šime Vidas — yes, they can (although you have to escape them to use in a CSS selector).

Comment: `TABLE > TBODY > TD`? How is that working in any browser? You are missing a `TR`. Please show us real HTML and CSS.

Comment: Is this working for you: http://jsfiddle.net/hPdFJ/

Comment: @Quentin, happy now? This production code I have to deal with. There's no other stuff I can show here.

Comment: @Šime Vidas, I tried all the usual means of fixing this with no luck. If there's something else at play in the system, it's beyond my control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
padding: auto; width: 100% /* if not used */; height: 100%;/* if not used */
```

inside the `td` style.

You should have given us the styles applied to that class (`block.productgrid.image`) so we could better see what to do.

Comment: the only css on the containing td is: text-align: center;

Comment: Then it may be the size of the td. If the size is not greater than the image, then the image can't be aligned.

Comment: ... when I check the dimensions on Friebug, (layout tab) the TD is 197  x 138 and IMG is 125 x 100

Comment: BINGO: after setting width:100% on the containing TD all's well! But why?!?

Comment: Width 100% uses the full size of the parent node, which is the width of TR. In your case, it may also refer to the page's width.